# About the calculation of cohomology groups on projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Chapter III, section $5$ of Hartshorne, we want to calculate the cohomology groups of sheaves $\mathcal{O}_X(n)$ on a projective space $X=\mathbb{P}_A^r$, where $A$ is a noetherian ring.

We are going to prove the following statement:
$$H^i(X,\mathcal{O}_X(n))=0, 0<i<r, \forall n\in \mathbb{Z}.$$

First we can claim that
$$H^i(X,\mathcal{F})_{x_r}=0,$$
where $\mathcal{F}=\bigoplus_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}\mathcal{O}_X(n).$

We consider the exact sequence of sheaves
$$0\rightarrow \mathcal{F}(-1)\rightarrow \mathcal{F}\rightarrow \mathcal{F}_H\rightarrow 0,$$
where $H$ is the hyperplane $x_r=0$, and $\mathcal{F}_H=\bigoplus_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}\mathcal{O}_H(n)$.

Then it gives a long exact sequence of $A$-modules as follows,
$$0 \rightarrow H^{r-1}(X,\mathcal{F}(-1)) \xrightarrow{\times x_r} H^{r-1}(X,\mathcal{F})\rightarrow H^{r-1}(X,\mathcal{F}_H)$$
$$\xrightarrow{\delta} H^r(X,\mathcal{F}(-1)) \xrightarrow{\times x_r} H^r(X,\mathcal{F})\rightarrow H^r(X,\mathcal{F}_H) \rightarrow 0,$$
note that $H^{r-2}(X,\mathcal{F}_H)=0$ by the induction hypothesis.

In order to show that the first $\times x_r$ above is an isomorphism, we need to prove $\delta$ is **injective**.

So now **my question** is:
Why this $\delta$ is **defined** by $\times x_r^{-1}$ as Hartshorne said?

Although we know that im$(\delta)=$ ker$(H^r(X,\mathcal{F}(-1)) \xrightarrow{\times x_r} H^r(X,\mathcal{F})$

is generated by $x_0^{l_0}x_1^{l_1}\cdots x_{r-1}^{l_{r-1}}x_r^{-1}$ in degree $n=\Sigma_{i=0}^{r-1} l_i-1$,
but how to conclude that $\delta$ is exactly the map $\times x_r^{-1}$?